# how to change direction of the vuetify menu on the fly

Tags: vue.js, popover, vuetify.js

I started recently using **vuetify** in my **vue** based application. Using v-menu component as popover in my application and popover direction mention **bottom** as like below code snippet. But when there is no space to fit popover content at bottom of the activator element I want to change direction to the **top**. I am not sure how to archive it can anyone help me on this.

```html
<v-menu :offset-y="true" :bottom="true">
    <v-btn slot="activator"
        color="primary"
        dark>
        Dropdown
    </v-btn>
    <div>
        <p>This is Test</p>
        <p>This is Test</p>
        <p>This is Test</p>
        <p>This is Test</p>
        <p>This is Test</p>
        <p>This is Test</p>
        <p>This is Test</p>
    </div>
</v-menu>
```

Comment: Just remove `:bottom="true"`, the `offset-y` property will handle the direction.

Comment: If I mention only offset-y, first it tries fit popover at the bottom in case place is not available then it moves to top. What If I want to place initially at the top ?                         What I see, only with offset-y can't specify popover direction properly.

Comment: @subbu - did you find any solution for it ?

Comment: @Bujji I didn't find a solution on this.